# Contabilizar columna de Caracteres en R

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, r-dplyr

Buenas me encuentro estudiando R y estoy atorado en como poder contar una columna de caracteres y poder determinar la que mas aparezca en esta columna. Alguna idea de que puedo emplear para poder hacer esta Frecuencia?
Ya intente con:
`sum(datos$Delegacion)` pero simplemente me arroja el error de que no puede sumar en char.
`Error in sum(datos$Delegacion) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument`

EDIT:

Simplemente tuve que agarrar los datos de esa tabla y poder sacar el max de esa tabla, asi quedo parte del codigo:

`tabla <- table(df$Delegacion)`

`names(tabla[tabla==max(tabla)])`

Comment: podrías especificar un poco mas acerca de que quieres contar y que quieres determinar que te aparezca?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias opciones para realizar contajes en R.

Creando una tabla:

```
nombres <- c(rep("gato", 10), rep("perro", 5), rep("tortuga", 20))

id <- c(1:35)

library(data.table)

i_nombres <- data.table(id, nombres)

class(i_nombres$nombres)
```

Tabla de contajes usando R-base

```
table(i_nombres$nombres)
```

Contajes con paquete dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

count(i_nombres, nombres)
```

Contaje con paquete data.table

```
library(data.table)

i_nombres[, .(.N), .(nombres)]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jose, me funciono creando la tabla. Muchas gracias!